# problem in lauching the jupyter notebook from anaconda prompt

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda

I installed tensorflow gpu one day ago at that time it was working fine, but now when I am trying to launch the notebook i am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .json_compat import get_current_validator, ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\lib\site-packages\nbformat\json_compat.py", line 10, in <module>
    import jsonschema
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jsonschema._format import (
  File "C:\Users\sumanta\anaconda3\envs\tf_2.5\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_format.py", line 240, in <module>
    @_checks_drafts(draft7="idn-hostname", raises=idna.IDNAError)
AttributeError: module 'idna' has no attribute 'IDNAError'
```

Answer (score 0):

A very, very basic solution - but what fixed this a while back for me was `pip install idna`. Give it a shot.

Comment: When I am trying pip install idna